# ggplot2: how to produce smaller points

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graphics

I have a large dataset that I am plotting using a scatter plot. These points have a unique combination of x,y and therefore they don't overlap, but some of them are very close to each other therefore I'm plotitng them with small size.

1- How to produce smaller point symbols (smaller `size`) so that the areas are proportional. In this example, the last point does not have an area proportional to the `size`. I was expecting it 10 smaller than the middle one e.g.:

```
df <- data.frame(c1 = 1:3, c2 = c(1,1,1))
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x= c1, y = c2), size = c(1, 0.1, 0.01))
```

2- How does the `size` in ggplot2 matches the R graphics `cex` argument e.g.:  `plot(df$c2 ~ df$c1, cex = c(1, 0.1, 0.01))`. 
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. Have you run the code in your question? The `ggplot` code produces 3 points of different sizes. If you want even smaller points, use even smaller numbers. If you run the `plot` code in your question, it also produces points of different sizes, but not quite the same as the `ggplot` code... So whether or not `size` "matches" `cex` depends on what you mean by "match" - they work more or less the same but don't produce identical results.

Comment: Hi @Gregor, thanks. The size (diameter) of the points is not proportional to the size value as you can see with the last two points.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing size of proportional dots in ggplot map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460050/changing-size-of-proportional-dots-in-ggplot-map)

Comment: That's a lot clearer - I'd recommend editing your question to make it state the aspects you actually want help with.

Answer (score 10):

You can try

```
geom_point(shape = ".")
```

this will make the point 1 pixel in size.

This is from page 70 of ggplot2 second edition by H Wickham

Comment: But this is no longer a circular point, but a squared-off period

Comment: True, but it is also the smallest possible image on the screen. Are not all pixels rectangular?

Answer (score 10):

There is a `size =` argument to `geom_point`, but you either specify a size for all points:

```
+ geom_point(size = 0.5)
```

Or you map the size to one of the columns in your data using `aes`:

```
+ geom_point(aes(size = c2))
```

In the latter case, you can control the range of sizes using `scale_size_continuous`. The default is min = 1, max = 6. To get *e.g.* min = 2, max = 8:

```
+ geom_point(aes(size = c2)) + scale_size_continuous(range = c(2, 8))
```

- Note that the "ggplot2 way" is to map data to geoms, not to assign values to each observation
- and no, size here is different to `cex`

Answer (score 0):

The issue here might be that a point in ggplot consists of an interior and a border part (for lack of better wording). The interior is controlled with `fill`, `alpha`, and `size`, and the border with `color` and `stroke`. With `size`, you will, therefore, only change the size of the interior, while the line thickness of the border will remain unchanged. Try setting `strike = 0`and see how that changes your point size.